# Can't get Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to install

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Sony Vaio desktop. I put the DVD in the drive and get the icon on the bottom showing a keyboard and arrow, and then the screen goes blank and does not ever get beyond that point.

I have tried to install Ubuntu 10.10 on the computer, and that one works, but not the 14.04 I just downloaded. It is not a bad disk, because I have tested it on my laptop and it boots from the DVD just fine.

My computer is a PCV-RZ44G, not sure what specs are needed, but it is a Pentium 4, 2.8 GHZ with a NVIDIA GeForce FX5200 video card with 128 MB memory. Have no idea why it does not boot, unless 14.04 LTS is not compatible with that video card.

Computer used to run Windows XP Media Center, but since XP is no longer supported and I had to replace the HD, I decided to install Ubuntu instead. Also tried booting with no HD connected, same result.

I would like to run the latest version of Ubuntu if possible, and if 14.04 is not compatible, can someone tell me what the latest version I should be able to run would be? The only versions I have a DVD for are 14.04 and 10.10.

Any assistance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: 14.04 is currently the latest and the best supported stable version. The only other version supported currently is 12.04, but most people would recommend against using it, since it's over two years old.

Your hardware looks quite decent, and should be fine for 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The installation with the live CD is pretty demanding for an old computer. How much ram memory do you have?
I would also suggest you to try lubuntu, as low weight version of ubuntu.